# how to get configuration parameter into a command

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to get a configuration parameter into a command.

I have added the parameter in the `app/config/config.yml` under the `parameters` key.

I can use it in a Controller using `$this->getParameter("PRAMETER_NAME")` in an action to do some stuff manually.

I'm writing a command to do the same stuff automatically with a CRON job.

I can't find how to get the parameter in the command.

Comment: @fyrye I'm using Symfony 3.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Argument Binding

In Symfony 3.4 or later, the [recommended approach](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding) is to use [Autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html) and [Argument Binding](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type). Allowing for the declaration of the variable name to be "bound" as an argument for ALL services defined in the config file, without needing to explicitly specify each service the parameter is used in.

In the same configuration file that defines the command service and autowiring, add the `bind` option to the `_defaults` specification, along with the desired variable name for the parameter.

*app/config/services.yml*

```yaml
parameters:
    PARAMETER_NAME: 'test'

services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $PARAMETER_NAME: '%PARAMETER_NAME%'
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests}'

    # Additional Services Below Here
```

Afterwards, Symfony will automatically pass the parameter value to the bound variable name when it is specified as an argument for the service constructor.

*src/AppBundle/Command/MyCommand.php*

```php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MyCommand extends Command
{

    private $PARAMETER_NAME;

    public function __construct($PARAMETER_NAME)
    {
        $this->PARAMETER_NAME = $PARAMETER_NAME;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // ...

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        dump($this->PARAMETER_NAME);
        exit;
    }

    public static function getDefaultName()
    {
        return 'app:my_command';
    }
}
```

---

### Parameter Injection

Another approach, to avoid needing to override `__construct`, is to inject the parameter value using a method, by extending the service definition using `calls`.

*app/config/services.yml*

```yaml
parameters:
    PARAMETER_NAME: 'test'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests}'

    AppBundle\Command\MyCommand:
        calls:
            - [setParameterName, ['%PARAMETER_NAME%']]

    # Additional Services Below Here
```

*src/AppBundle/Command/MyCommand.php*

```php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MyCommand extends Command
{

    private $parameterName;

    // ...

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        dump($this->parameterName);
        exit;
    }

    public function setParameterName($value)
    {
        $this->parameterName = $value;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, dependency injection can be used to inject the Container or ParameterBag into the command, allowing it to function similarly to a Controller.

> Injecting the entire Container or ParameterBag is [highly
> discouraged](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/dependency_injection.html#avoiding-your-code-becoming-dependent-on-the-container).
> **Only inject the parameter(s) and service(s) that are needed**
> **instead.**

In either of the below examples, ensure `autowire` and `autoconfigure` are enabled.

*app/config/services.yml*

```yaml
parameters:
    PARAMETER_NAME: 'test'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests}'

    # Additional Services Below Here
```

### ContainerAwareCommand

*(depreciated as of Symfony 4.2 - removed in Syfmony 5.0+)*

Using `ContainerAwareCommand` works similarly to Parameter Injection, but instead of calling `setParameterName()`. With `autowiring` and `autoconfig` enabled, Symfony will automatically inject the entire container using `setContainer()` implemented from `ContainerAwareInterface`.

*src/AppBundle/Command/MyCommand.php*

```php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    // ...

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        dump($this->getContainer()->getParameter('PARAMETER_NAME'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

### ParameterBag Injection

*Requires Symfony 4.1+*

To inject the [ParameterBag](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service) with Dependency Injection when `autowire` is enabled, add `ParameterBagInterface` to the service constructor.

*src/AppBundle/Command/MyCommand.php*

```php
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MyCommand extends Command
{

    private $parameterBag;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
         $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
         parent::__construct();
    }

    // ...

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        dump($this->parameterBag->get('PARAMETER_NAME'));
        exit;
    }

    public static function getDefaultName()
    {
        return 'app:my_command';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can inject the container into the command declaring it `ContainerAware` (worse), you can inject the `ParamterBag` as a service (better) or you can inject the parameter in the command constructor (best).

In your command you have to accept the parameter in constructor. Ex:

YourCommand.php:

```php
<?php

class YourCommand extends Command {
  public function __construct(string $parameter) {
    parent::__construct('app:my-command');
    $this->parameter = $parameter;
  }
}
```

services.yaml

```yaml
services:
  YourCommand:
    arguments:
      - '%parameter_name%'
```

Comment: I made the third method, it's perfect !

Comment: Please do not forget the `parent::__construct();` to ensure that the `Command::configure()`  is called and the `InputDefinition` is declared.

Comment: I forgot and Symfony told me ^^